# How to use nntplib module?

Tags: python, nntp

When I use first example in Python's `nntplib` module documentation, there are some errors.

```
>>> from nntplib import NNTP
>>> s = NNTP('news.gmane.org')
>>> resp, count, first, last, name = s.group('gmane.comp.python.committers')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\nntplib.py", line 354, in group
    resp = self.shortcmd('GROUP ' + name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\nntplib.py", line 268, in shortcmd
    return self.getresp()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\nntplib.py", line 223, in getresp
    resp = self.getline()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\nntplib.py", line 215, in getline
    if not line: raise EOFError
EOFError
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Try `s = NNTP('news.gmane.org' ,readermode=True)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works well.

Comment: Welcome. I just added the answer below with some more details for the future references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `s = NNTP('news.gmane.org', readermode=True)`

As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/nntplib.html#nntplib.NNTP):

> If the optional flag `readermode` is true, then a `mode reader` command is
> sent before authentication is performed. Reader mode is sometimes
> necessary if you are connecting to an NNTP server on the local machine
> and intend to call reader-specific commands, such as `group`. If you get
> unexpected NNTPPermanentErrors, you might need to set readermode.